# How can I have a Twitter feed floating at the right of my content?

Tags: html, css

How can I display my Twitter-Widget next to my content on the right? I tried many ways but nothing semed to work and I have no clue how to achieve that. The widget should be centered in the right slot of the page and normaly scroll with the page. Because widgets dont work here I replacet it with an div called `id="theActualWidget"`.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-image: url(media/image/background.gif);
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-position: center top;
  background-size: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #111010;
}

#in {
  width: 800px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(3, 3, 3, 0.5);
  color: #f7f7f7;
  font-family: "Helvetica";
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  font-size: 18px;
}

#in>* {
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-right: 40px;
}

#main {
  min-height: calc(100% - 186px);
  padding-top: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}

#header {
  background-color: #000000;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #161616;
  text-align: center;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  z-index: 99;
  position: relative;
  background: #000000 url("media/image/header.jpg") no-repeat center 10%;
  background-size: cover;
}

#page-title {
  font-family: "sloganfont";
  /* ODER "titlefont" was ist besser? */
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #ED1C24;
}

p {
  line-height: 130%;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
}

footer {
  background-color: #000000;
  border-top: 6px solid #161616;
  text-align: center;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 98;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  position: relative;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

#credit {
  font-family: "Helvetica";
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #555555;
  font-weight: 600;
}

#theActualWidget {
background-color: blue;
width: 400px;
height: 600px;

}



@media (max-width: 800px) {
  #in {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>My-Website</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header id="header">

  </header>
  <main>
    <div id="in">
      <h2 id="page-title">My Content</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
        sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et
        ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        <br>
        <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,
        no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
        duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        <br>
        <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,
        no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
        duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        <br>
        <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,
        no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
        duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        <br>
        <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,
        no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
        duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
      <div id="twitter">
        <div id="theActualWidget">
        </div>
      </div>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <p id="credit">© 2017 XXXXXXXXX</p>
    </nav>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can do this with number of ways, from top of my head:
You will need to give #in div float left and width, for example 50% and #right div give it float right or left and a width as well 50%.
Now you will be able to see them them beside each other and you will be able to play with values as your requirements.